# How can I convert between scientific and decimal notation in Perl?

Tags: perl, decimal, notation, scientific-notation

I know this is a total newbie question, but the answer may not be obvious to many new programmers.  It wasn't initially obvious to me so I scoured the Internet looking for Perl modules to do this simple task.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) does the trick

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $decimal_notation = 10 / 3;
my $scientific_notation = sprintf("%e", $decimal_notation);

print "Decimal ($decimal_notation) to scientific ($scientific_notation)\n\n";

$scientific_notation = "1.23456789e+001";
$decimal_notation = sprintf("%.10g", $scientific_notation);

print "Scientific ($scientific_notation) to decimal ($decimal_notation)\n\n";
```

generates this output:

```
Decimal (3.33333333333333) to scientific (3.333333e+000)

Scientific (1.23456789e+001) to decimal (12.3456789)
```

Comment: I had to use "%.10f" to get the decimal value, as "g" kept it in scientific notation. I'm using Perl v5.10.1 on Ubuntu.  Nice post, thanks!

Comment: I couldn't get `sprintf` to work but `printf` and  `%.10f` instead of `g` worked fine. Perl version  5.14.2.

Comment: @terdon, you're right. Notice that `%.10f` works with `sprintf` as well. You could make your comment into a separate answer maybe?

Comment: @n.r. no need, the basic idea is to use the printf family. I suggested an edit instead.

Comment: One difference with using "%.10f" compared to "%.10g" is that the value will have additional zeros out to the specified field size (10 digits in this case): `12.3456789000`. Using "g" instead of "f" in the format string will omit those extra zeros.

Answer (score 3):

On a related theme, if you want to convert between decimal notation and [engineering notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation) (which is a version of scientific notation), the [Number::FormatEng](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Number%3A%3AFormatEng&mode=all) module from CPAN is handy:

```
use Number::FormatEng qw(:all);
print format_eng(1234);     # prints 1.234e3
print format_pref(-0.035);  # prints -35m
unformat_pref('1.23T');     # returns 1.23e+12
```